# How to split Windows Terminal into 8 equal panes "programmatically"?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

I am trying to split the new Windows Terminal into 8 equal panes by running one or more commands.

Recently Microsoft added support for splitting the new Windows Terminal into panes "programmatically" by using the parameters:

```
split-pane -H or -V (Horizontal or Vertical pane)
```

I have tried a dozen combinations of the parameters, but it splits the terminal windows "wrong".

Here is an example:

```
wt `; split-pane -V -p "pwsh" `; split-pane -H -p "pwsh" `; split-pane -V -p "pwsh"
```

Here is the desired result:
[image: Screenshot of 8 equally split panes in Windows Terminal]
How would I achieve this programmatically? It's possible to do in the Windows Terminal by using hotkeys ALT+SHIFT+MINUS and ALT+SHIFT+PLUS (see screenshot).

Answer (score 3):

A little late but here is a solution

```
"startupActions": "-p \"Bash\" ; split-pane -p \"Bash\" -V ; move-focus left ;  split-pane -p \"Bash\" -H ; move-focus right;split-pane -p \"Bash\" -H ; move-focus up ; move-focus left ; split-pane -p \"Bash\" -V ; move-focus down ; split-pane -p \"Bash\" -V ; move-focus right ; move-focus up ; split-pane -p \"Bash\" -V move-focus down ; split-pane -p \"Bash\" -V"
```

It is not the prettiest but it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Currenty this is simply not possible using `wt.exe` on its own however if you are using **WSL** you could do it with [`tmux`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki).

In order to get equal spacing of the panes with wt.exe on its own, split-pane size control would need to be supported and [that feature](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/6298) is currently in the backlog. Also I think you would probably need to 'nest' the split-pane commands and that is not yet possible in Window Terminal either.